# Why Have Modern *duilian*'s become 成语+3 Random Characters?

Tags: poetry

I keep seeing parts of **modern** *duilian*'s made of one 成语 + three random characters.

Something like: `国泰民安 + 增财富`

- How did *duilian* evolve to this level?

Comment: seems kind of a generalization... can you provide more examples?  Where do these duilian come from/where do you see them?  I know some high school teachers in China with very good Chinese (i.e., rigorous classical education) who can write terrific duilian, but I wouldn't expect the same quality from a pair you buy in a store, for example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This observation is merely coincidental. The first 4 characters need not come from classical Chinese idiom (成語), and the remaining 3 are by no means random.

[Couplet (Duilian)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couplet_(Chinese_poetry)) has specific rules. The linked article has a list of requirements and its etymology.

For example, the cliché duilian

> 天增歲月人添壽
>
> 春滿乾坤福滿門

"天增歲月" is not a recognized chengyu, but means "As heaven attains greater age"; "人添壽" is not random but has to relate to it, meaning "people enjoy longer years".

Moreover, a line of 7 characters is common but it is not a requirement.

For example, the famous (but modern (19th century)) couplet in [Temple of Zhuge Liang](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%88%90%E9%83%BD%E6%AD%A6%E4%BE%AF%E7%A5%A0) in Chengdu

> 能攻心則反側自消從古知兵非好戰
>
> 不審勢即寬嚴皆誤後來治蜀要深思

also meet the requirement.

[image: Duilian]